# YAML on BeagleBone Black

Tags: linux, debian, yaml, beagleboneblack, ros

I am try to install the image_transport package for ROS (Indigo) on a BeagleBone Black running Debian Wheezy.  I installed yaml on the BBB using

```
apt-get install libyaml-dev

apt-get install lbyaml-cpp0.3
```

When I go to compile the image_transport package using

```
catkin_make install -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo
```

I get the following error:

> [ 12%] Built target camera_calibration_parsers Linking CXX executable
>   /home/debian/image_transport_ws/devel/lib/camera_calibration_parsers/convert
>   /home/debian/image_transport_ws/devel/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so:
>   undefined reference to 'YAML::Emitter::StartedScalar()'
>   /home/debian/image_transport_ws/devel/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so:
>   undefined reference to 'YAML::detail::node_data::set_null()'

I'm lost on how to correct this.  Any suggestions?

python-yaml is also installed if that matters.